# How to reuse the same react native instance across multiple actvities?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a brownfield Android application that has multiple activities, some of which are native and some of them react native.

What I wanted to know is that is there a way I can reuse the same react instance across all of my react native activities?

Right now, whenever we are creating a new activity that uses React Native, we have to initialize a new React Native instance and sync a lot of data along with rehydrating our entire redux store. This process is painfully slow and also consumes a lot of memory.